# How to expand the length of an input text/number based on it's `value` attribute?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, html-table

I have a `form` that I'm using to modify a `SQL` `table`s values. I can easily get everything to populate using `PHP`; however, I'm having issues getting the `input` fields to size properly. I'm hoping there's an easier way than brute forcing the `CSS` to work the way I want...

`PHP`/`HTML`

```
echo "<table class='modify woSub'>";
echo "<tr><th>KeyID</th><th>Rx Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Alt Name</th><th>Patient</th><th>Prescriber</th><th>Dose/Pill</th>
<th>Dose Metric</th><th colspan='2'>Quantity / Frequency</th><th class='box'>AM</th><th class='box'>Noon</th><th class='box'>PM</th>
<th class='box'>Bed</th><th class='box'>PRN</th><th>Last Fill</th><th>Pills Filled</th></tr>";
echo "<form class='modifyForm' action='modify.php' method='post'>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prescriptions WHERE patient = '$patient' ORDER BY rxPrimeName";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric'  value='" . $row['keyID'] . "' name='keyID' disabled/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric'  value='" . $row['rxID'] . "' name='rxID'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['rxPrimeName'] . "' name='rxPrimeName'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['rxAltName'] . "' name='rxAltName'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $patient . "' name='patient' disabled/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['prescriber'] . "' name='prescriber'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric' value='" . $row['dpp'] . "' name='dpp'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='" . $row['dppMetric'] . "' name='dppMetric'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input class='split' type='text' inputmode='numeric'  value='" . $row['frequency'] . "' name='frequency' style='border-right: none !important'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input class='split' type='text' value='" . $row['freqMetric'] . "' name='freqMetric' style='border-left: none !important'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='am' value='am' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='pm' value='noon' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='pm' value='pm' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='bed' value='bed' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='prn' value='prn' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='date' value='" . $row['lastFill'] . "' name='lastFill'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric' value='" . $row['pills'] . "' name='pills'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
```

`CSS`

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 1400px;
}

th,
td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
th {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
td>input {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 5px;
}
.box {
    width: 10px;
}
.split {
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is the `PHP`>`Table`>`Form` I'm using. No, I haven't put in a `submit` portion yet, and I'm not too worried about that. I'm just working on aesthetics right now.

Here is a snippet of what it's showing exactly as-is:

[IMGUR Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ni5z.jpg)

If you look at the first 4 `columns`, this is the area I'm trying to get to fit. I would like this all to fit the size of the largest value with a tiny bit of `padding` (like 2-5`px`).

Everything I've found online is for how to have the input auto-expand when typing, but I'm trying to do it based on the `php` value that is being pushed into the `value` `attribute`.

Comment: Since resizing will have to be calculated on client side, you can apply the same concept as you've found for expanding input, but not during typing, but at page load.

Comment: @vanowm I was afraid of that. I appreciate the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit complicated javascript method. The idea is to create an element with exact same style as input field. Then load into it string from each input field sorted by column and find the longest one. Then set input width per column.

```js
const setWidth = (() =>
{
  //clone style from <input> into our hidden div
  const div = document.createElement("div"),
        selector = '.modify input[type="text"]'; //input fields

  div.className = "hiddenBox";
  for(let i = 0, style = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(selector)); i < style.length; i++)
    div.style[style[i]] = style[style[i]]; //copy all styles into hidden div

  document.body.appendChild(div);

  return () =>
  {
    let max = [];
    for(let i = 0, input = document.querySelectorAll(selector); i < input.length; i++)
    {
      div.textContent = input[i].value; //load text into hidden div
      if (div.clientWidth > ~~max[input[i].parentNode.cellIndex])
        max[input[i].parentNode.cellIndex] = div.clientWidth; //record widest size
    }
    for(let i = 0, box = document.querySelector(".modify"); i < max.length; i++)
      max[i] && box.style.setProperty("--width"+(i+1), max[i] + "px"); //set CSS variable for input width for each column
  }
})();

setWidth(); //set <input> width



//ignore everything below

generateRows(10) //add 10 rows
function generateRows(num)
{
  // generate additional rows
  for(let i = 1, tr = document.querySelector(".modify tr:not(:first-child)"); i < num; i++)
    tr.parentNode.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));

  randText(); //generate text
}

function randText()
{
  for(let i = 0, input = document.querySelectorAll('.modify input[type="text"]'); i < input.length; i++)
  {
    input[i].value = "";
    let len = ~~(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    while(input[i].value.length < len)
    {
      input[i].value += String.fromCharCode((~~(Math.random() * 2) ? 97 : 65) + ~~(Math.random() * 26));
      if (!~~(Math.random() * 10))
        input[i].value += " ";
    }
  }
  setWidth();
};
```

```css
.modify td:nth-child(1) input {width: var(--width1);}
.modify td:nth-child(2) input {width: var(--width2);}
.modify td:nth-child(3) input {width: var(--width3);}
.modify td:nth-child(4) input {width: var(--width4);}
.modify td:nth-child(5) input {width: var(--width5);}
.modify td:nth-child(6) input {width: var(--width6);}
.modify td:nth-child(7) input {width: var(--width7);}
.modify td:nth-child(8) input {width: var(--width8);}
.modify td:nth-child(9) input {width: var(--width9);}
.modify td:nth-child(10) input {width: var(--width10);}
.modify td:nth-child(17) input {width: var(--width17);}

.hiddenBox
{
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -200000vh !important;
  width: unset !important;
  white-space: pre !important;
  padding: initial !important; /* delete this if some text doesn't fit */
  border: 0 !important; /* delete this if some text doesn't fit */
}
```

```html
<button onclick="randText()">Generate again</button>

<table class='modify woSub'>
<tr><th>KeyID</th><th>Rx Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Alt Name</th><th>Patient</th><th>Prescriber</th><th>Dose/Pill</th>
<th>Dose Metric</th><th colspan='2'>Quantity / Frequency</th><th class='box'>AM</th><th class='box'>Noon</th><th class='box'>PM</th>
<th class='box'>Bed</th><th class='box'>PRN</th><th>Last Fill</th><th>Pills Filled</th></tr>
<form class='modifyForm' action='modify.php' method='post'>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric' value='' name='keyID' disabled/></td>
      <td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric'  value='' name='rxID'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' value='' name='rxPrimeName'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' value='' name='rxAltName'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' value='' name='patient' disabled/></td>
      <td><input type='text' value='' name='prescriber'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric' value='' name='dpp'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' value='' name='dppMetric'/></td>
      <td><input class='split' type='text' inputmode='numeric'  value='' name='frequency' style='border-right: none !important'/></td>
      <td><input class='split' type='text' value='' name='freqMetric' style='border-left: none !important'/></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='am' value='am' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='pm' value='noon' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='pm' value='pm' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='bed' value='bed' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='prn' value='prn' /></td>
      <td><input type='date' value='' name='lastFill'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' inputmode='numeric' value='' name='pills'/></td>
      </tr>
</form>
</table>
```